# JS auto-increment with calling function parameter

Tags: javascript, increment, auto-increment

How can we build an auto-increment function inside a function with parameter. I have a function - when page is loading, some values return in it. Like

```
// val is the parameter which returns almost 1000 values

formatter: (val) => {
    var n = 0;
    function increment(i) {
     i++
    return i;
    }
    console.log(increment(n)) // result: 1/1/1/1/1/1/
//expected result: /1/2/3/4/5...
}
```

What I want to do is a function in formatter that increment value from 1 to last val. Just 12345...999 like. Each val change add 1 to 1.

Comment: Typo? `returns` -> `return`? Also `n` doesn't seem to be used?

Comment: sorry spelling mistake

Comment: What you're doing calls it once, rather than returning the incremented value. call the function again with that incremented value. Make sure you have a conditional to break the recursive loop.

Comment: What is `formatter`? Looks like a property or something, but please provide self-consistent syntax.

Comment: @a.mola I could'nt understand what u mean;

Comment: @trincot It is the apexchart label formatter

Comment: How do you call `formatter`?

Comment: You should provide JavaScript syntax that works. Currently `formatter` is a *label*. Please provide an object notation that is useful for testing.

Comment: What do tou want to do? Increase the val parameter +1?

Comment: @AlexandroPalacios No I want to increment value from 1 to last val . just 12345...999 like. Each val change add 1 to 1

Comment: @trincot doesnt matter, you can see as the function like `function formatter(val)`

Comment: @MuhammedArslan, it does matter. See my answer. If your case is a plain `function`, then ask the question like that. It is not good that you post code which is ambiguous, as taking this literally will *not* define a function with the name `formatter`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code for auto-incrementing a number

```
const formatter = () => {
  let n = 0;
  const increment = () => {
    return ++n;
  }
   
  console.log(increment()) // 1
  console.log(increment()) // 2
  console.log(increment()) // 3
  console.log(increment()) // 4
}


formatter()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reassign the value of n; i is increased within the scope of the function, and when returned, is not used anywhere by your program.

This will work as you expect, for example (syntax changed mildly):

```
function formatter (val) {
    var n = 0;
    function increment(i) {
     i++
    return i;
    }
    console.log(n = increment(n)) // result: 1
//aspected result: /1/2/3/4/5...
console.log(n = increment(n))
console.log(n = increment(n))
console.log(n = increment(n))
console.log(n = increment(n))
}

formatter()
```

It's possible to achieve what you're doing (at least in terms of syntax), but you'd need to use a global or class variable, and the function would be redundant (your increment(n) would be interchangeable with n++).

Answer (score 0):

Your function will create `n` each time it is called and reset it to 0.

Instead use some place to store the last generated number, which is not local to the function's execution context. For instance, you could use the `formatter` function object to store that last generated number.

For instance:

```js
let obj = {
    formatter(val) { // Make it a `function`
        let i = this.formatter.i = (this.formatter.i || 0) + 1;
        console.log(i);
    }
};

obj.formatter(); // 1 
obj.formatter(); // 2
obj.formatter(); // 3
```

Or, why not reserve a property for it, in the object of which `formatter` is a property:

```js
let obj = {
    n: 0,
    formatter(val) {
        ++this.n;
        console.log(this.n);
    }
};

obj.formatter(); // 1 
obj.formatter(); // 2
obj.formatter(); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Examples up to 10:

- Using a `recursive` function:

```js
let obj = {
  formatter: (val) => {
    function increment(i) {
        console.log(i);
        if (i < 10) increment(++i);
    }
    increment(val);
  }
};

obj.formatter(1);
```

- Using a `for()` loop:

```js
let obj = {
  formatter: (val) => {
    for (i = val; i <= 10; i++) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
};

obj.formatter(1);
```

- Using a `while()` loop:

```js
let obj = {
  formatter: (val) => {
    while (val < 10) {
      console.log(++val);
    }
  }
};

obj.formatter(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide a closure, and return the increment function:

```js
const incrementGenerator = () => {
  let n = 0;
  
  return function(){
    n++;
    return n;
  }  
}

var increment = incrementGenerator();

console.log(increment());
console.log(increment());
console.log(increment());
console.log(increment());
```